# powershell - how to auto add and remove dhcp reservation with csv

Tags: powershell, csv, dhcp

My client.csv format is:

```
ScopeId,Name,ClientId,Ipaddress
10.10.10.0,Computer1,1a-1b-1c-1d-1e-1f,10.10.10.10
10.10.10.0,Computer2,2a-2b-2c-2d-2e-2f,10.10.10.11
10.10.10.0,Computer3,3a-3b-3c-3d-3e-3f,10.10.10.12
```

My client.csv format (when a user's ClientID is null):

```
ScopeId,Name,ClientId,Ipaddress
10.10.10.0,Computer1,1a-1b-1c-1d-1e-1f,10.10.10.10
10.10.10.0,Computer2,2a-2b-2c-2d-2e-2f,10.10.10.11
10.10.10.0,Computer3,,10.10.10.12
```

When I run my powershell with my csv, auto add dhcp server reservations is successful.  But when the user's ClientID is null, PowerShell could not auto remove dhcp server reservations.  Does my PowerShell script have some problem?

```
$ComputerName="WIN-OO4RE715BV8.test.com"
if (!$args) { 
    Write-Host "client.csv"
} 
ELSE
{
    $dhcpdata=Import-CSV $args
    foreach ($dhcp in $dhcpdata){ 

        $ScopeId=$dhcp.ScopeId
        $Name=$dhcp.Name
        $ClientId=$dhcp.ClientId
        $IPAddress=$dhcp.IPAddress
        if ($ClientId -eq $null) {
            Remove-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $ScopeId -Name $Name -ClientId $ClientId -IPAddress $IPAddress 
        }
        Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $ScopeId -Name $Name -ClientId $ClientId -IPAddress $IPAddress    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ComputerName="WIN-JA5I029SJFM.test.com"
if (!$args) { 
    Write-Host "client.csv"
} 
ELSE
{
    $dhcpdata=Import-CSV $args
    foreach ($dhcp in $dhcpdata){ 

        $ScopeId=$dhcp.ScopeId
        $Name=$dhcp.Name
        $ClientId=$dhcp.ClientId
        $IPAddress=$dhcp.IPAddress
        Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $ScopeId -Name $Name -ClientId $ClientId -
        IPAddress $IPAddress
        if(!$ClientId)
        {
            echo Remove-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName "$ComputerName" -IPAddress $IPAddress
            Remove-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName "$ComputerName" -IPAddress $IPAddress
        }
    }
}
```